Unable to retrieve other users' tasks using the MS Graph API
While working with the Microsoft Graph API, I'm trying to list the tasks of a specified (i.e., not me) user.
If I use the Graph Explorer with the following URL (which I found by navigating through the Resources on the left-hand side of the Graph Explorer) ...

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/planner/plans/{plannerPlan-id}/buckets/{plannerBucket-id}/tasks

... I receive the following response ...
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://tasks.office.com:444/taskapi/V3.0/users('REMOVED: A USER ID')/details/plans('REMOVED: A PLAN ID')/buckets('REMOVED: A BUCKET ID')/tasks'.",
        "innerError": {
            "message": "No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/navigation/navigation/key/navigation/key/navigation'.",
            "date": "2024-04-09T08:12:20",
            "request-id": "67b71584-da23-4e51-823c-ff3ed3521f34",
            "client-request-id": "8fda60ca-7ee2-82bc-5035-52c3bb31503c"
        }
    }
}

The user, plan and bucket ID that I'm specifying have all been obtained from other Graph API requests.
I also get the same response by using (C#) ...
response = await graphClient.Users[userId].Planner.Plans[planId].Buckets[bucketId].Tasks.GetAsync();

... from the Microsoft.Graph library.
Also, if I go 'back up' the URL and use only ...

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/planner

... then I receive ...
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "You do not have the required permissions to access this item.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-04-09T08:18:54",
            "request-id": "54f31cca-cf01-4390-bae7-5a1f00afc1ed",
            "client-request-id": "63094425-9963-d539-55af-2e9e15d62d7e"
        }
    }
}

I then clicked on Modify permissions, and it lists the following as being necessary:

Tasks.Read
Group.Read.All
Tasks.ReadWrite

All of these have been granted.

So why can't it find the tasks in the specified plan/bucket, and why does it appear to be missing permissions?
UPDATE:
The Tasks.Read.All permission has been granted (since before the original post) as type Application.
Also, I can obtain another user's tasks by calling ...
graphClient.Users[userId].Planner.Tasks.GetAsync()

... but that retrieves every task across all buckets and all plans. The following two methods exist in the Microsoft.Graph library and are listed in Graph Explorer ...
graphClient.Users[userId].Planner.Plans[planId].Buckets[bucketId].Tasks.GetAsync()
graphClient.Users[userId].Planner.Plans[planId].Tasks.GetAsync()

... both those methods would help to narrow the scope of the returned tasks, but calling either of those methods results in an exception ...

Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://tasks.office.com:444/taskapi/V3.0/users('MY USER ID')/details/plans('MY PLAN ID')/tasks'.

I am 100% certain that the planId and bucketId arguments are correct - I'm taking them from the result of other calls and am using them in other successful calls.
Is this a bug, is another permission needed, or have I misunderstood something?

I'm afraid Tasks.Read.All should be required instead of Tasks.Read because you are trying to access all users' tasks.

The application already has Tasks.Read.All - as type Application. Would granting Tasks.Read.All with type Delegated make any difference?

UPDATE: It's not possible to grant Tasks.Read.All as Delegated. So what else can I try?

try as Application instead of Delegated....

Tasks.Read.All is already assigned as type Application. I get this permissions error despite having granted that permission.

Thanks for your confirmation! Do you grant admin consent for this api permission? I remembered that application type of permission requires admin consent, otherwise it won't take effect.

@TinyWang - Please see my update in the OP.

yes actually I also noticed this issue when I tried to find the corresponding Graph API yesterday based on your http url. But the result is that I can' find that specific API indeed. I'm afraid that we don't have users/userId/planner/planId/buckets/bucketId/task. Here's the API document related. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/planner-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

@TinyWang So why do the methods exist? Why does the code compile? Why does the library allow me to build such a request if there's no endpoint for it?

@awj Could you include the document where you are referring that contains those methods?

@Sridevi I'm afraid that awj got his code based on the Graph SDK.. and I don't know why the methods exist as well. Maybe this is a beta feature which would be release in a near future. Just like you see, no compile error https://i.sstatic.net/UubuM.png

@TinyWang Yes, even I believe the same. It's not giving compile error as those methods are currently under progress and will be released in future. But, as of now they are not supported.

Exactly - here you can see 3 method calls; each are allowed / will build without any errors, but the first two return the No HTTP resource was found exception. So these are going to be built eventually but for now, to fetch a user's tasks in a plan or in a bucket, I have to fetch that user's tasks for the entire application, then filter the results myself?

Yes @awj as of now, that's the only way to fetch filtered tasks based on planId and bucketId till the methods are released to production use as a workaround.

The Graph Explorer also lists it - that's just future-proofing as well, is it?

Yes, you are correct! Those methods are currently undergoing updates and will be released soon,

So why are they listed as v1.0 and not as beta?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


I agree with @user2250152 and @TinyWang, you cannot read tasks of other users using Delegated permissions.

As Graph Explorer works with Delegated permissions, you can only get tasks of signed-in user. When I tried to get the tasks of other users via Graph Explorer, I too got same error like this:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userID/planner/tasks

Response:

To get the tasks of other users, you need to switch to client credentials flow by granting permissions of Application type that generates app-only token.
In my case, I registered one application and granted Tasks.Read.All permission of Application type by granting admin consent:

When I ran below sample C# code that uses client credentials flow, I got the response successfully with other user tasks details like this:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var tenantId = "tenantId";
        var clientId = "appId";
        var clientSecret = "secret";

        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        try
        {
            var tasks = await graphClient.Users["userId"].Planner.Tasks.GetAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Tasks:");
            foreach (var task in tasks.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine($"Task Title: {task.Title}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Task ID: {task.Id}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Task Bucket ID: {task.BucketId}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Task Plan ID: {task.PlanId}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{exception.GetType().FullName}: {exception.Message}");
        }
    }
}

Response:

Reference:
List tasks - Microsoft Graph
UPDATE:
The methods that you are referring does not exist with /users endpoint.
The below method exists that retrieves list of tasks associated with specific plan:
graphClient.Planner.Plans["{plannerPlan-id}"].Tasks.GetAsync();

But this method does not exist and throws error saying "No HTTP method found".
graphClient.Users["userId"].Planner.Plans["planId"].Tasks.GetAsync()

You can only use this endpoint to list planner tasks of other user. Note that, this endpoint does not support optional query parameters like $select or $filter to get filtered results.
As of now, you can only filter the response of all tasks with planId and bucketId manually  like this:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var tenantId = "tenantId";
        var clientId = "appId";
        var clientSecret = "secret";

        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        try
        {
            var tasks = await graphClient.Users["userId"].Planner.Tasks.GetAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Filtered Tasks:");
            foreach (var task in tasks.Value)
            {
                // Check if task's bucketId and planId match the desired values
                if (task.BucketId == "your_bucketId" && task.PlanId == "your_planId")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Task Title: {task.Title}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Task ID: {task.Id}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Task Bucket ID: {task.BucketId}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Task Plan ID: {task.PlanId}");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{exception.GetType().FullName}: {exception.Message}");
        }
    }
}

Response:


Please read my update in the OP.

Check the updated answer and I believe it's not giving compile error as those methods are currently under progress and will be released in future. But, as of now they are not supported.

The same issue for me, even the request GET /v1.0/me/planner/plans/{plan_id} fails with the error

No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/navigation/navigation/key'.

I'm not able to read tasks of other users with delegated permission. Based on this, Tasks.Read and Tasks.ReadWrite allow to read tasks of signed-in user, not of other users.
You will need to use application permissions Tasks.Read.All, call the endpoint GET /v1.0/users/{user_id}/planner/tasks and filter tasks by planId and bucketId. From my testing, the server side filtering neither by planId nor bucketId is supported. It must be done on the client
var result = await graphClient.Users[userId].Planner.Tasks.GetAsync();

